# facebook php signed request and oauth redirection for mobile web

Tags: php, facebook

I have an issue with redirection uris, signed requests and mobile web Facebook apps and I just cant pin point where I am screwing this up.

I have a canvas app at example.com running an app that uses signed request to grab its users data. I decided to launch a mobile version so that my mobile users could use the app so I created a new directory example.com/m and made a mobile version.

At the moment the normal app is working perfectly, but the mobile app is stuck in an infinite loop once the user allows the oauth privileges. I have tried experimenting with different URLS but I haven't been able to figure it out. For the mobile the signed request is empty and I cant figure out why.

In my Facebook settings I have this set as the canvas url:
example.com
this set as the mobile web url
example.com/m

In my normal browser app I am using the following code to get the oath from Facebook:

```
$redir = "https://apps.facebook.com/example";
if(isset($_REQUEST["signed_request"]))
{
  $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
  $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
}

if (empty($data["user_id"]))
{
    $fb -> go("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={$app["appid"]}&redirect_uri=$redir&scope={$app["permissions"]}&response_type=token");
    exit;
} else 
{
    $fb -> access_token = "access_token=" . $data["oauth_token"];
}
```

This code is working fine, in my mobile version i have this code (I have tried a lot of different urls here and there but still cant get around the issue)

```
$redir = "https://apps.facebook.com/example/m";
if(isset($_REQUEST["signed_request"]))
{
  $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
  $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
}


if (empty($data["user_id"]))
{
    $fb -> go("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={$app["appid"]}&redirect_uri=$redir&scope={$app["permissions"]}&response_type=token");
    exit;
} else 
{
    $fb -> access_token = "access_token=" . $data["oauth_token"];
}
```

Comment: Just a comment. I figure that the signed request being empty is a sign that there is an issue with my mobile web redirection url in the facebook app settings. 

One possible solution might be to have the mobile web url xxx.com?mobile=true and then post the signed request over to the mobile version of the app?

Comment: When I do what I suggested above i get an error that my app is not configured for mobile... so confused.